# Почему невозможно подключиться к локальному mongodb внутри Docker-контейнера?

Tags: mongodb, docker

Имеется такой Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER test

RUN \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927; \
    touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list; \
    echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.com/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-enterprise/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-enterprise.list; \
    sudo apt-get update; \
    sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-enterprise;
```

Собираю его и запускаю:

```
docker build . -t "test"
docker run -t -i test bash
```

Внутри шелла контейнера обращаюсь к mongo:

```
root@bacaf47d90a4:/# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: test
2016-10-02T18:59:12.327+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-10-02T18:59:12.327+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:229:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Запускаю mongo демон:

```
root@bacaf47d90a4:/# mongod --fork --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 24
child process started successfully, parent exiting
```

После этой процедуры все работает. Такая же история на Ubuntu 16, Debian 7. Пробовал mongo 3.2.1 и 2.6.0.

Вопрос: почему невозможно подключиться к локальному mongodb внутри Docker-контейнера при запуске (в первом случае)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому, что по идеологии докера у вас в докере должен быть запущен основной процесс в foreground. То есть здесь вместо bash-а вы должны запускать монго:

```
docker run -t -i test bash
```

Но не в фоне, а как основной процесс. А еще лучше прописать запуск процесса в Dockerfile.

А "подключиться" к контейнеру, если очень надо, вы всегда можете потом по:

```
docker exec -ti test bash
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как подключаться знаю )

Comment: При запуске таким образом возникает такая же ошибка, разницы никакой нет (docker run -t -i eabf7b74b6ac mongo). Причем строки по инициализации mongodb в докер-файле я взял из официального пакета с репозитория. Похоже, что дело на в идеологии докера )

Comment: Не, не клиента таким образом запускать, а сервер, который и будет основным процессом в контейнере.
То есть, docker run -t -i eabf7b74b6ac mongod --logpath /var/lib/mongodb/mongodb.log --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb

Только смотрите, что бы он в бекграунд не ушел.